# Does updating Ubuntu 14.04 to 15.04 affect packages that I have previously installed?

Tags: 14.04, nodejs

I would  like to update Ubuntu 14.04  to 15.04, but I am currently working on a project using NodeJS. Specifically, I am using Nodecopter to make autonomous control for an AR.Drone 2.0. I am worried about whether or not updating Ubuntu will remove or alter what I have done so far.

Comment: It should not remove or alter your codes. You can check which version of NodeJS is in the repository of Ubuntu 15.04, and if it is significantly different from the version installed in your system. If you installed NodeJs directly from the website, then it should not get updated.

Comment: Comparing http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/nodejs and http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/nodejs there doesn't seem to be any differences between the repository versions.

Comment: Notice than to upgrade from 14.04 to 15.04 you first need to upgrade to 14.10.

Comment: I didn't know about this,  I just had updated a computer running Ubuntu 14.10, so this is the reason I wanted to update my own computer which run Ubuntu 14.04. Thanks for that info.

Comment: If you want to avoid potentially breaking changes in node, you can always manage Node versions completely separate of regular package management using [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). You can even have multiple Node versions installed for easier testing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrading Ubuntu will not remove any nodejs packages from your system.
It is fine to update your system.